# Trying to append the textfield value to another textfield

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing some basic javascript where i am choosing some value from the popup and that value is appearing in the textfield. Now there is a button on the side of the textfieldfield, which when clicked will transfer its value to the another textfield as comma separated.

I mean the new textfield will have values as comma separated and not replaced.

I am doing a code like this

```
<input type="text" class="inputs" style="width:70px;" name="color1" id="color1" value="" maxlength="7" size="7"> 
<a href="javascript:addtoTextField('color1')"><img src="icon_add.gif" alt="Add to text Box above" title="Add to text Box above" border="0"></a>

function addtoTextField(cFieldName) {
                var objTxt = document.getElementById('sta');    
                objTxt.appendChild(cFieldName);
            }
```

Another text field where i need to pass value

```
 <input type="text" name="sta" id="sta" class="inputs" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Textbox element can't have child nodes, it only got a value. So to append value of other textbox as comma delimeted string, have this:

```
function addtoTextField(cFieldName) {
    var oField = document.getElementById(cFieldName);
    var valueToAdd = oField.value;
    if (valueToAdd.length === 0)
        return; //don't add empty values
    var objTxt = document.getElementById('sta');    
    var existingValues = (objTxt.value.length === 0) ? [] : objTxt.value.split(",");
    existingValues.push(valueToAdd);
    objTxt.value = existingValues.join(",");
    oField.value = ""; //clear textbox
    oField.focus(); //bring focus back
}
```

[Live test case.](http://jsfiddle.net/utK98/1/)

The above will also clear the sender textbox value and re-focus it for next input.

Comment: That works, but how to clear the color field, after it is being inserted